# Uploading google drive is giving exception

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

```
    01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907): com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:224)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:836)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:456)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithBackOffAndGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:478)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeUploadInitiation(MediaHttpUploader.java:428)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:326)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:420)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.example.driveproj040114.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:100)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907): Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
01-05 22:14:54.106: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
01-05 22:14:54.116: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:192)
01-05 22:14:54.116: W/System.err(5907):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:217)
01-05 22:14:54.116: W/System.err(5907):     ... 10 more
```

I have followed the android quick start[here](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) properly , and i have entered perfect sha1 and package name but i stuck here from last 2 days , Im sure I'm getting creditinals  in on create using `usingOAuth2` even though i'm getting `Error auth token fail` can any body have a look into this, Thanks in advance

EDIT:
After changing scope to "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" I am getting 403 forbidden error

```
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001): Error retrieving auth token
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001): {
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):   "code": 403,
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):   "errors": [
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):     {
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):       "domain": "usageLimits",
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):       "message": "Access Not Configured",
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):       "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):     }
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):   ],
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):   "message": "Access Not Configured"
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001): }
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):         at com.examplenew.sampleprojectcloud.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:113)
01-07 09:58:18.048: E/DriveCloudHelper(4001):         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Solution
 got the solution (I have registerd my app in new console, Its not working from a week, Today I tried to register in old console as mentioned in quick start) Register your api in old console is solves my problem...

Comment: No , after changing scopes , I ave got 403 error but i have configured drive api well, still i stuck here..look at my edit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution (I have registerd my app in new console, Its not working from a week, Today I tried to register in old console as mentioned in quick start) **Register your api in old console is solves my problem**...

Comment: Can you paste the url to the old console?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this might help you but I've encounter with this issue trying to figure it out what can be the problem.

MAKE SURE YOU PROVIDED THE CORRECT SHA1 & PACKAGE NAME IN GOOGLE CONSOLE.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: yes i have provided coreect sha1 and package name, and i activate drive api also..